# How to Reference Router Generated Controller from View

Tags: controller, ember.js, ember-router

I have the following code in my Ember app...

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('messages', { path: '/messages' }, function() {
        this.route('message', { path: '/:message_id' });
        this.route('unanswered', { path: '/unanswered' });
    });
});

App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, playlist) {
        controller.set('model', App.Message.find());
        //debugger;
    }
});

App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    testvar: 'hi',
    testme: function() {
        debugger;
    }
});

App.MyButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Sort'),

    click: function() {
        App.MessagesController.testme();   
    }
});
```

...and in my template...

```
{{view App.MyButton}}
```

On the view's click event, how can I call the testme() method on the controller instance (of MessagesController) that was generated by my router?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

From within your `MyButton` view click event handler you can do you can do this:

```
this.get('controller').send('testme');
```

> Note: for this to work the `MyButton` have to be a child of the `MessagesView`

Example:

```
App.MyButton = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Sort'),
  click: function() {
    this.get('controller').send('testme');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps